# Write data frame to Excel file stored in Microsoft Teams using Graph API

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am new to working with APIs and especially MS Graph API so please excuse my ignorance.

I work with data in R which is similar to Python, I have a data frame which I need to write to an Excel file stored on a Teams channel. Specifically I need to write the data frame to a certain tab in the Excel file.

Is this possible to do using the Graph API?

I have [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0) that it's possible to upload large files using Graph API but is it possible to write data to a specific sheet of a file?

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Answer (score -1):

We have Graph API's to work with Excel file/Sheet.

You can write date to specific ExcelSheet using below API call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/worksheets/{id|name}
```

Please go through below documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/worksheet-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1rSkJww2Dk